# How to cover these scratches on my door?

Tags: doors, varnishing, scratches

[Cat scratches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZL1w.jpg) on varnished wooden door: tried rubbing walnuts, only hides the smallest scratches not the big ones.

[image]

Is there any paint or varnish I could use in an attempt to cover this mess?

Comment: You sure they are from a cat?  The best way is to sand the door down and refinish.  The other way if you wanted paint is to fill them in with filler then paint, but the door looks too nice to use paint on it.

Comment: If they are surface scratches, you will be amazed at what rubbing them with a walnut or almond nut will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options available to you. You can try a walnut putty stick from your home store to fill i the larger cracks. For plain surface scratches, there are walnut stains that you can blend in. You can then dab on some varnish to finish it off. It will take a little experimenting to get it just right.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand your sentence "there are walnut stains that you can blend in" though, could you elaborate please? Do you think https://www.amazon.co.uk/Furniture-17PCS-Markers-Scratches-Carpenters-Bedposts/dp/B085GJQ3CR/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=walnut+putty+stick&qid=1637431577 would work?

Comment: @drake035 If just the finish has been scratched off, then you could get a can of walnut liquid stain and brush it in with a small brush or toothpick. Yes, those petty sticks will work... I've got three cats

Comment: You mean like this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Furniture-Clinic-Stain-250ml-Walnut/dp/B08CXDRVFQ/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=walnut%2Bliquid%2Bstain&qid=1637501616? I can't decide between buying this or the markers, which one would you try first?

Comment: The markers are better for deeper scratches. I'd start out with the stain.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that first then.

Answer (score 0):

**Eraser.**

If you are referring to that wavy, vaguely sinusoidal horizontal line that is not cat.  That is kid, and it looks like pencil to me.  Try a pencil eraser.

And even better than you trying a pencil eraser, ask kid about the line and then ask kid to erase it.  Grampa used to say "him what messes up cleans up".